# Using Curl to login to a website, go to a link, again submit a form and get the output

Tags: php, forms, cookies, curl, authentication

I am trying to log into a website, then go to a link and then submit a form to get the desired data. I want to do it using cURL. I have achieved success in loggin into the website. The login redirects me to the profile page.

Now I need to follow a link and then submit a form! but when i do that using CURL the session is invalidated. I get the **JSESSIONID in a cookie.txt** file i used to store the cookie created. All the examples i have seen are just about loggin into a website or just a registration form submission.that is just one single **POST** request!

How do I go to another link and then submit another form using curl after I have successfully logged in and stored the cookie?

I am using WAMP as my local server.

```
<?php
$username="myusername"; 
$password="mypassword"; 
$url="http://onlinelic.in/LICEPS/Login/webLogin.do";
$referer = "http://onlinelic.in/epslogin.htm"; 
$postdata = "portlet_5_6{actionForm.userName}=".$username."&portlet_5_6{actionForm.password}=".$password;
$cookie = "cookie.txt" ;
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION,false); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
logIntoLocator(); 
curl_close($ch);

function logIntoLocator()
{
    $pincode = "731234";
    $locatorType = "P";
    $url = "http://onlinelic.in/LICEPS/appmanager/Customer/CustomerHome?_nfpb=true&_windowLabel=Cust_Agent_Locator_portlet_25_2&Cust_Agent_Locator_portlet_25_2_actionOverride=%2Fportlets%2Fvisitor%2FAgentLocator%2Flocating";
    $referer = "https://customer.onlinelic.in/LICEPS/appmanager/Customer/CustomerHome?_nfpb=true&_windowLabel=CustomerLocatorsPortlet_1&_cuid=RC_t_832059&_pagechange=AgentLocator";
    $postData = "Cust_Agent_Locator_portlet_25_2wlw-radio_button_group_key:{actionForm.agentRadioOption}=".$locatorType."&Cust_Agent_Locator_portlet_25_2{actionForm.agentOption}=".$pincode;
    $cookie = "cookie.txt" ;
    $agentCurl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($agentCurl, CURLOPT_URL, $referer); 
    curl_setopt ($agentCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt ($agentCurl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0");
    curl_setopt($agentCurl,CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION,true);
    curl_setopt ($agentCurl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
    curl_setopt ($agentCurl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
    curl_setopt ($agentCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
    curl_setopt ($agentCurl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    curl_setopt ($agentCurl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt ($agentCurl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt ($agentCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    curl_setopt ($agentCurl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    $result = curl_exec ($agentCurl);    
    echo $result;   
}
```

If you like to give it a try the username is "manashch1" and the password is "nokia1105*". login there and go the AgentLocator and there u can enter pincode as 731234 and get the data needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach the cookie(s) to CURL. There are two options:

1. You can do this all manually by reading the cookie, and attaching manually using

   ```
   $ch = curl_init();
   $sCookie = 'JSESSIONID=' . $sessionIDSavedEarlier . '; path=/'; 
   curl_setopt ( $ch , CURLOPT_COOKIE, sCookie );
   ... rest of POST
   ```
2. You can use a "cookie jar" (probably easiest)

   ```
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
   ... rest of POST
   ```

(Making sure you can read/write to a file called "cookie.txt" - if you have multiple users using hte script, then make that file unique for each user through a PHP session!)

Comment: used that! no luck!! the jsessionid is never sent with the request header. and now i have a really strange  problem...i have jsessionid in cookie file and the request header shows Cookie:PHPSESSID=blahblahblah :O

Comment: Thanks for the code - can't see anything glaringly wrong. Suggestions: use the option CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION to prevent previous session variables being loaded (or delete/unlink cookie.txt to be sure), close the first curl session (just in case it doesn't update the cookie jar file until after curl is closed). You can verify this by using file_m_date to check the modified date before calling the second function. But those are items to try, not guaranteed results!

Comment: but to carry the session i need to use the previous session right??? anyway none of them works..the file is being changed each time..the jsessionid changes inside the cookie file. :(

Comment: leave the last part for now..how can i just go to a link that is inside the profile page  after loggin in. even the redirect says that the session invalidated.

Comment: Ah - I think you have the CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION the wrong way round in your code. Start with true (in the first, to ignore prevoius session cookies) and false (or omit, in the subsequent pages).

Answer (score 0):

So you want to login, get the page and then goto a page which is only accessible once logged in?

If so, then ensure that the cookie.txt is writeable by your script and check the url doesn't contain any special parameters (like your session ID). Are you extracting it from the profile page.

If you know the content of the form, you should just be able to post direct to that forms destination, but you may need to set the referring page to the site your logging into.

Comment: cookie file folder is writable..and there are no special params like sessionid in the url...m posting the code here.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
```

Use this in your cUrl script .
Where

> $postfields = 'form1=value1&form2=value2&form3=value3';

where form1,form2.. are the 'name' attributes of your inputs .

Comment: i know that..i have already done that..check the code./..its been 5 days now and its the pain in the ass..boss wants it to be done

Comment: maybe curl_getinfo  function might help

Comment: Also try to put curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  on after curl init . And are sure ssl verifier to be set true ?

Comment: the site uses https so i set that to true. and i set that..it gives me the JSESSIONID.. the same id that is being stored in cookie.txt